# Duvida escrita no codigo

Tags: c

//Ajuda, Preciso fazer um menu com a opção switch da linguagem C, mas quando escolho uma das opções ela //finaliza automaticamente, ser dar a opção para escolher outros pratos e consequentemente somando o //
valor e escrevendo no final.....agradeço a ajuda

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int opcao = 0;
    float totalPedidos = 0.0;
    
    
        printf("\n--------------------------------\n");
        printf("\n--       Lanches Outlast      --\n");
        printf("\n-- Queremos o melhor de você  --\n");
        printf("\n--   1 - DEDO DE MOÇA - R$ 15,00  --\n");
        printf("\n--   2 - PASTEL DE FRANGO - R$ 5,00  --\n");
        printf("\n--   3 - SUCO SABOR LARANJA - R$ 4,00      --\n");
        printf("\n--   4 - HIENA MAL PASSADA - R$ 20,00      --\n");
        printf("\n--   5 - JAVALI NA BRASA - R$ 40,00      --\n");
        printf("\n--   0 - TENTAR SAIR                 --\n");  
        scanf("%i", &opcao);
        
        switch( opcao )
    {
    
        case 1:
            totalPedidos = 15.00 + totalPedidos;
        break;
        case 2:
            totalPedidos = 5.00 + totalPedidos;
        break;
        case 3:
            totalPedidos = 4.00 + totalPedidos;
        break;
        case 4:
            totalPedidos = 20.00 + totalPedidos;
        break;
        case 5:
            totalPedidos = 40.00 + totalPedidos;
        break;
        case 0: 
            printf:("\nSeu pedido ficou em %f\n", totalPedidos);
        break;
        default:
            printf("\nNão temos essa oferta\n");    
        break;
        

    } 
    return = 0;
}
```

Comment: O programa finaliza pois você não colocou ele em um `loop`, coloque ele em um `loop` `do{}while()` e remova o `case 0` deixe isso com o `while`

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo?...se possivel obeviamente

Comment: Veja a resposta do @Paulo Martins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O switch é uma estrutura condicional, tal qual o *if* e *else*. Tudo que ele faz é testar o código apresentado e retornar um valor.
Se você quiser que seu código seja executado varias vezes precisa executar uma estrutura de repetição. No c você tem a opção do *For* e *While*. No exemplo abaixo o ***do*** executa a ação pela primeira fez, e depois ficara executando novamente até que você digite 0.
Mas se você é novo em programação e ainda não aprendeu estrutura de repetições não se preocupe com isto agora, você vai chegar lá!

```
do{
    printf("\n--------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n--       Lanches Outlast      --\n");
    printf("\n-- Queremos o melhor de você  --\n");
    printf("\n--   1 - DEDO DE MOÇA - R$ 15,00  --\n");
    printf("\n--   2 - PASTEL DE FRANGO - R$ 5,00  --\n");
    printf("\n--   3 - SUCO SABOR LARANJA - R$ 4,00      --\n");
    printf("\n--   4 - HIENA MAL PASSADA - R$ 20,00      --\n");
    printf("\n--   5 - JAVALI NA BRASA - R$ 40,00      --\n");
    printf("\n--   0 - TENTAR SAIR                 --\n");  
    scanf("%i", &opcao);
        switch(opcao)
        {
    
            case 1:
                totalPedidos = 15.00 + totalPedidos;
            break;
            case 2:
                totalPedidos = 5.00 + totalPedidos;
            break;
            case 3:
                totalPedidos = 4.00 + totalPedidos;
            break;
            case 4:
                totalPedidos = 20.00 + totalPedidos;
            break;
            case 5:
                totalPedidos = 40.00 + totalPedidos;
            break;
            case 0: 
                printf("\nSeu pedido ficou em %f\n", totalPedidos);
            break;
            default:
                printf("\nNão temos essa oferta\n");    
            break;
            
    
        } 
    } while(opcao!=0);//repita enquanto a opcao for diferente de 0
```

Comment: opa obrg....eu aprendi as estruturas de repetições...o switch para mim é uma materia nova...mas estou com dificuldade para organizar isso de maneira correta...novamente obrg

Comment: O switch nada mais é do que vários if, else if escrito de uma maneira diferente! Você pode substituir o case 1: para if(opcao=1){} por exemplo. Só lembra que ela precisa do break no final